# How do I crop the image with 10 pixel offset?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

this is my **input** image:

[image]

and this is what I need as an **output (without 10px padding)**:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that in Swift?

Comment: So you're trying to zoom the map portion, without the rest being effected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Core Graphics [cropping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping) method to crop a `CGImage`. Just implement a custom cropping method to take top, bottom, left and right instead of a `CGRect` parameter as follow:

```
extension CGImage {
    var image: UIImage { return .init(cgImage: self) }
    func cropping(top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) -> CGImage? {
        let width = CGFloat(self.width)
        let height = CGFloat(self.height)
        precondition(left + right < width && top + bottom < height)
        return cropping(to: .init(origin: .init(x: left, y: top), size: .init(width: width-left-right, height: height-top-bottom) ))
    }

}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let cropped = image.cgImage?.cropping(top: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100, right: 100)?.image
```